# when opening mdb file, it connects to a DB

Tags: ms-access

how do i specify which DB it connects to? i am opening an access file that has sql code in it and it automatically wants to connect to a specific file. how can i change this setting?

Comment: As I understand it (and as a quick web serach seems to confirm), MDB files are simply MS Access databases, so when you open the MDB file, you're opening a particular database.  Are you connecting to a different database than the one contained in the file?

Comment: yes its connecting to a different file

Comment: You'll have to edit the SQL so that it no longer references the database that you don't want it to. What version of Access are you using? We can try to help you alter the query based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this manually hold the shift key down and open the MDB.  Then run the `Linked Table Manager` and choose a different MDB containing the tables you want. If Access 2003 see `Tools -> Database Utilities -> Linked Table Manager`.  If Access 2007 I think it's on a similar labelled item behind the Office button.

If you want to do this programmatically then see Relink Access tables from code
http://www.mvps.org/access/tables/tbl0009.htm.   I store the path and file name of the tables MDB, typically called the backend (BE) MDB, in an iNI file located in the same folder as the front end (FE) MDB.   Although you could use the registry.  This way when I release a new copy of the FE MDB/MDE it reads that path and file name and automatically relinks to the customers BE MDB.